# DataGridTemplateColumn used CellEditingTemplate combobox - Auto drop down on single click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn CellEditingTemplate used combobox in a DataGrid. I would like to be able to click on the cell one time and have the combobox drop down

Xaml code here :

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding collection}"  Margin="0 20 0 0" x:Name="item_list" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="410" CanUserResizeColumns="False"  SelectionMode="Single" CellEditEnding="item_list_CellEditEnding" CanUserAddRows="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"  HeadersVisibility="All" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFBDB7B7" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFCBC4C4" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" GridLinesVisibility="All"   >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn   x:Name="list_itemname" Header="Item Name" Width="2.5*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="cs_itemname" Text="{Binding pitemnames}"   />
                </DataTemplate>                                
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox  Padding="0,0,0,5" x:Name="itemname_list" SelectedItem="{Binding pitemnames, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding pitemname}"  IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" KeyUp="itemname_list_KeyUp" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

purchase_item_list.cs class here :

```
public class purchase_item_list : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        dBA dba = new dBA();
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        public string _pitemname;   
        public ObservableCollection<string> pItemname = new ObservableCollection<string>();


        DataTable item_dt = new DataTable();
        public purchase_item_list()
        {
            item_dt.Clear();
            Dictionary<string, string> field = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            field.Clear();
            field.Add("id", "");
            field.Add("item_name", "");
            dba.getData("item_list", field, "item_status='store'", item_dt);

            for (int j = 0; j < item_dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                pItemname.Add((item_dt.Rows[j][1].ToString()));
            }
        }

        public string pitemnames
        {
            get { return _pitemname; }
            set
            {

                if (_pitemname != value)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(value);
                    _pitemname = value;

                    RaisePropertyChanged(this, "pitemnames");

                }

            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<string> pitemname

        {
            get
            {
                return pItemname;
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

used purchase_item_list class in here :

```
ObservableCollection<purchase_item_list> collection = new ObservableCollection<purchase_item_list>();
```

I have to click twice to open the ComboBox. Is there a way to open the ComboBox with only one click into the cell?

Answer (score 0):

If you able to handle the event like DataGridComboboxTemplate_Loaded for ComboBox then you can try below code.

```
ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Padding="0,0,0,5" x:Name="itemname_list" SelectedItem="{Binding pitemnames, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding pitemname}"  IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" KeyUp="itemname_list_KeyUp">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```